# Using HttpService to export as CSV: Unexpected token N in JSON

Tags: node.js, angular

Currently, I am trying to export csv using nodejs as backend and angular as front end.

I know that the error 'Unexpected token N in JSON' means that there is a JSON parsing error. Which means that I need to change the {responseType: "blob" as "json"}. But there is a problem because I cannot include these in the parameters of httpServices because it only accepts HttpParams as parameters

So in respect to that I have tried these

1) `` return this.httpService.get(`/chatbots/get/${id}/download`, {responseType: 'text'}) `` which returns an error since httpService only accepts HttpParams as parameters

2) Change HttpServices from @core/services to HttpClient but it didnt work since I have another API call inside the current API call which uses HTTPServices.

3) Change it to a post method where I can attach {responseType: "blob" as "json"} but it didnt work and anyway it should work as a get?

Currently, output already shows the text in csv.

```
router.get('/get/:id/download', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res, next) => {
   ..... 
   console.log(output) 
   res.attachment('test.csv')
   res.send(output)
}
```

In services:

```
import { HttpService } from '../../@core/services';
constructor(
      private httpService: HttpService, ) {}
...
 downloadCSV(id: string) {
      return this.httpService.get(`/xxxx/get/${id}/download`)
   }
```

in component

```
  export() {
    if (this.id) {
      this.chatbotService.downloadChatbot(this.id)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
        const fileName = `${this.id}-test.csv`;
        saveAs(blob, fileName);
    })
    }
  }
```

Even though the status is 200, it says

SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:22263:51)
    at ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a request made with HttpClient is considered to have a JSON response.
To get a CSV, you can force a text response with

```js
downloadCSV(id: string) {
  return this.httpService.get(`/xxxx/get/${id}/download`, {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

You can also read this part of the documentation : https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType

Comment: I have tried that and the problem is that because this is httpService not the angular http. It will give this error: Argument of type '{ responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpParams'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'responseType' does not exist in type Argument of type '{ responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpParams'.... Is there any other way to set responseType?

Comment: Oddly enough, I think I encountered this scenario... Try the following ```downloadCSV(id: string) { const resType = 'text'; return this.httpService.get(`/xxx/get/${id}/download`, {responseType: resType}); }```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried this but it gave me the same error:  'responseType' does not exist in type 'HttpParams'...

Comment: Oh! My bad. You need to add the responseType in your service making the request (the one using `HttpClient`), not in your `downloadCSV()`.

Comment: Thank! I managed to add it in. I also found that res.json works but res.send doesn't work which still gives me JSOS parse error.....